# Run .Net application on XP,Vista,Windows7 ... 32 and 64 bit

Tags: winforms

I got an application from a client. The application has 2 setup files one for 32 bit OS and other for 64 bit windows OS.

I want to combine them and i want to make 1 exe that runs on all the windows OS and on 32 and 64 bit.

What i need to do ?

Regards,
Behroz

Answer (score 2):

Since: "I **got** an application from a client."

I would recommend using [DotNetInstaller](http://dblock.github.com/dotnetinstaller/) which is a *bootstrap* for installers.

Then just package *both* setup files and configure DNI to run the correct setup depending upon the target machine. (It can also be used to install the correct .NET version.)

.. or, ask the client to produce a unified installer :)

Comment: thank you for the reply. But i donot want to use the DotNetInstaller as i will have to manage both the setups. I have the code for both the setups. How can i generate unified installer ?

Comment: Depends how the setups are, naturally. MSI *cannot* be [at least in a trivial manner] be used for a cross-bitness installer. While maintaining two VS Setup Projects can be a little bit of a challenge, I have found that approach with DNI works well for ensuring the correct architecture dependencies are deployed.

Comment: I think i was not clear. I was saying that i have the complete source code for the application( including the setup projects). How can i merge the applications when i the source codes ?

Comment: The first comment made that clear. My comment followed it up. If *all* dependencies are 32-bit then use a *single* 32-bit installer. Otherwise, see my recommendation, which is *still* to use DNI with two setup projects. There is also [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) (and InstallShield), although I would recommend the MSI (from the VS Setup) inside the DNI package.

Comment: @user1470127 I have wrestled with this before and it either requires using something like DNI or *not using* VS Setup Projects and MSI or *possibly* running a custom tool like Orca by hand. MSI *does not* like cross-bitness. I found the two setup projects relatively simple and flexible. DNI can be run in an automated fashion as part of the build step, so once the setup projects are created it requires minimal maintenance. (This also has the advantage of keeping MSI for admin-deployments and an executable for end-user deployments.)

Comment: Another solution might be to just ship *all* architecture version modules (while distributing *only* a 32-bit MSI with 32-bit or version-neutal executable) and then "select" the proper-bitness versions (as a "post install" step or dynamically in the program). The exact method of deployment and if shared/GAC deployment is required will alter this viability.